# Erro no converter do JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Estou com problemas no converter do JSF, sempre retorna `null`.

Converter Projeto:

```
@FacesConverter("projetoConverter")
public class ProjetoConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext faces, UIComponent component, String valor) {

       try {
            Long codigo = Long.parseLong(valor);
            ProjetoDAO projetoDAO = new ProjetoDAO();
            Projeto projeto = projetoDAO.buscarPorCodigo(codigo);
            return projeto;
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext faces, UIComponent component, Object objeto) {
        if (!objeto.equals("")) {
            System.out.println(objeto);
            try {
                Projeto projeto = (Projeto) objeto;
                Long codigo = projeto.getPro_codigo();
                System.out.println(codigo);
                return codigo.toString();
            } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

Converter empresa:

```
@FacesConverter("empresaConverter")
public class EmpresaConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext faces, UIComponent component, String valor) {

        try {
            Long codigo = Long.parseLong(valor);
            EmpresaDAO empresaDAO = new EmpresaDAO();
            Empresa empresa = empresaDAO.buscarPorCodigo(codigo);

            return empresa;
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext faces, UIComponent component, Object objeto) {
        try {
            Empresa empresa = (Empresa) objeto;
            Long codigo = empresa.getCodigo();
            System.out.println(codigo.toString());

            return codigo.toString();           
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

DAOProjeto(Retorna lista do banco)

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Projeto> listarProjeto() {
    // Cria uma nova sess�o
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<Projeto> projeto = null;

    try {
        // Executa query de consulta
        Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Projeto.listarProjeto");
        projeto = consulta.list();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        // Fecha a sess�o
        sessao.close();
    }
    return projeto;
}
```

ProjetoBean(Preenche a combo do xhtml com a lista do banco)

```
public List<SelectItem> getImediatoselect() {

    if(Imediatoselect == null){
        Imediatoselect = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        ProjetoDAO projetoDAO = new ProjetoDAO();
        List<Projeto> listaProjeto = projetoDAO.listarProjeto();

        if(listaProjeto != null && !listaProjeto.isEmpty()){
            SelectItem item;
            for (Projeto projetoLista : listaProjeto) {
                item = new SelectItem(projetoLista, projetoLista.getPro_superiorImediato());
                Imediatoselect.add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return Imediatoselect;
}
```

DAOEmpresa (Retorna lista do banco)

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Empresa> listarEmpresa() {      
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<Empresa> empresa = null;

    try {
        // Executa query de consulta
        Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Empresa.listarEmpresa");
        empresa = consulta.list();
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        // Fecha a sess�o
        sessao.close();
    }
    return empresa;
}
```

EmpresaBean(Preenche a combo do xhtml com a lista do banco)

```
public List<SelectItem> getDepartamentoselect() {

    if (Departamentoselect == null) {
        Departamentoselect = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        EmpresaDAO empresaDAO = new EmpresaDAO();
        List<Empresa> listaEmpresa = empresaDAO.listarEmpresa();

        if (listaEmpresa != null && !listaEmpresa.isEmpty()) {
            SelectItem item;
            for (Empresa empresaLista : listaEmpresa) {
                item = new SelectItem(empresaLista, empresaLista.getDepartamento());
                Departamentoselect.add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    return Departamentoselect;
}
```

XHTML:

```
<p:outputLabel class="lt" value="Projeto:" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{usuarioBean.projeto.pro_projeto}"
    converter="projetoConverter">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione o projeto" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{projetoBean.projetoselect}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
<p:outputLabel class="lt" value="Superior Imediato:" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{projetoBean.projetoSelecionado}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione o superior" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{projetoBean.imediatoselect}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Mensagem de erro:

> Conversion Error setting value 'Projeto [pro_codigo=1,
>   pro_tipo=XXXXXXX, pro_projeto=XXXXXXX, pro_superiorImediato=XXXXXX
>   XXXXXXX]' for 'null Converter'.

Comment: Para retornar null esta entrando no catch. Ou seja esta ocorrendo algum erro. Tente capturar esse erro para entendermos melhor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim

```
converter="#{projetoConverter}"
```

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado